# 1H-NMR of vanillin details in Nilered video

Tags: organic-chemistry, spectroscopy, molecular-structure, nmr-spectroscopy, molecules

The image below is from a *Nilered video* [How to extract Vanillin from Vanilla Sugar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DELgSlr5Eyw), where he displays the $\ce{^1H}$-$\mathrm{NMR}$ of the final product created:

[image: 1H-NMR of vanillin]

The labels A, F, & E make sense to me, but I'm confused about D and C - I feel they should be swapped. To my understanding, B and D share a more similar chemical environment (though not identical), specifically they are near a $\ce{C-O}$ bond, moving their chemical shift to left. Also, the NMR peaks labelled D display a doublet, suggesting it is next to a single proton. Though B, C, and D are all next to a single proton, C is the odd one out.

Is this a case of me missing something, or is the picture mislabeled?

Comment: Assignment looks correct to me; don't forget the effect of the carbonyl group. Not quite sure what you're trying to say with C being the 'odd one out'. It's hard to see any multiplet structure in the screenshot, especially when two of the protons are overlapping with each other. But ideally, C should be a doublet of doublets as it is coupled to both B and D. On the other hand, B and D should both be doublets, and the D doublet should have a larger separation (coupling constant) than the B doublet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A few follow up questions then: 1) why is C coupled to both B & D (and not vice versa)? Does it have something to do with the benzene ring? You mention the carbonyl group - but what effect does that have? It appears far away from D/C/B, no?

Comment: Hm, thinking more about your carbonyl comment: is it because it is a meta-directing group and will change the environment of D. Likewise, -OH is meta-directing and again will change the environment of D.

I still don't understand why C should be a doublet of doublets.

Comment: You may want to go over this with a teacher if you have one. There are several problems with your comments. (1) B and D are both coupled to C, that's exactly why they appear as doublets. (2) Whether a group is o/p- or m-directing is not of any consequence here. They affect *all* protons on the ring, albeit not to the same extent (it depends on the group). (3) OH is most certainly *not* m-directing.

Comment: Right, I meant ortho-para for -OH. AFAIU, coupling occurs between protons on neighbouring carbons, but B is not neighbouring to C. I'm back to square one: what effect does the carbonyl have on the NMR?

Comment: Hm, I think I need to know more about coupling in benzene rings. This should help any future readers: https://www.sas.upenn.edu/~genette/NMRcoupling.pdf

Comment: There are spectra catalogues about IR and NMR spectroscopy (e.g., Sadtler, Aldrich) and compilations like [AIST's spectra collection](https://sdbs.db.aist.go.jp/sdbs/cgi-bin/cre_index.cgi) about organic compounds which may guide your training / self study.  If you are aware that each model-based predictions may err to some degree, you may consider predictions by software, e.g., advanced versions of sketchers like ChemSketch, ChemDraw, Chemdoodle or on-line services like [nmrshiftdb2](https://nmrshiftdb.nmr.uni-koeln.de/), too.

Answer (score 1):

"Normal" coupling is vicinal coupling across 3 bonds such as $\ce{H-C-C-H}$. For aromatics, *ortho*-coupling is of this type. But one can also get other couplings such as long range coupling, e.g., *meta*-coupling across 4 bonds. Long range coupling tends to be smaller than vicinal coupling (smaller $J$, the coupling constant). Thus C/D coupling is stronger than B/C coupling. And remember coupling must work both ways C to D, and D to C. The problem here is that B and C are overlapped so tough to see their multiplicities. C has higher shift than D due to position relative to the substituents.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] but I'm confused about D and C - I feel they should be swapped. To my understanding, B and D share a more similar chemical environment (though not identical), specifically they are near a C-O bond, moving their chemical shift left. Also, the NMR peaks labelled D display a doublet, suggesting it is next to a single proton. Though B, C and D are all next to a single proton, C is the odd one out.

First, in this statement, your assignment of "[...] B, C and D are all next to a single proton," is not correct. Clearly, B is not next to a single proton:

[image: NMR of Vanilin]

Now, after said that, your confusion is due to your ignorance of the electron withdrawing nature of aldehyde group $(\ce{CHO})$. That group is *ortho* to both $\ce{H_B}$ and $\ce{H_C}$  while *meta* to $\ce{H_D}$. Also, it is *para* to the electron donating $\ce{OH}$ group. Because they are *para* to each other, their effect may be optimized on each other. Regardless, $\ce{H_D}$ experiences significant electron density due to the electron donating $(\ce{OH})$ group at *ortho* position, while $\ce{H_C}$ (and $\ce{H_B}$) experiences significantly lesser electron density. When compare electron donating ability of $\ce{OH}$ group and $\ce{OCH3}$ group, it is safe to say that $\ce{OH}$ group has been the superior (compare $\sigma_{o,p}$ values of $\ce{OH}$ and $\ce{OCH3}$ groups). Since both $\ce{H_B}$ and $\ce{H_C}$ would experience significant electron withdrawing from $(\ce{CHO})$ group *ortho* to them in addition to experiencing aforementioned electron density from $(\ce{OCH3})$ group. Keep in mind that since $(\ce{CHO})$ group is *meta* to $\ce{H_D}$, it makes less effective on deshielding. Thus, based on these facts along, one can say safely that  $\ce{H_B}$ and $\ce{H_D}$ as well as $\ce{H_C}$ and $\ce{H_D}$ are significantly different chemically and magnetically. Therefore, their chemical shifts should be vastly different as assigned.

When compare the effects of substituents on $\ce{H_B}$ and $\ce{H_C}$, one can also say that they are very similar magnetically due to the effects of *meta* $\ce{CHO}$ group and *ortho, para* $\ce{OCH3}$ group (*ortho* to $\ce{H_B}$ and *para* to $\ce{H_C}$). The only difference is the $+I$ effect of $\ce{OCH3}$ group on each proton (with *pata* being the minimal). However, seemingly that difference is not been very significant in this case (again, compare $\sigma_{o}$ and $\sigma_{p}$ values of $\ce{OCH3}$ group for comparison). Thus, one can say that the chemical shifts of $\ce{H_B}$ and $\ce{H_C}$ should be very similar as assigned.

**Note:** The resonance of $\ce{H_D}$ should be a clear doublet since it does not have any *meta*-protons to have long-range couplings (usually $\pu{1-2 ppm}$). Yet, $\ce{H_B}$ and $\ce{H_C}$ are *meta* to each other and show multiplicity.